# zero is omitted while converting integer to string MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

See the following code I tried:

```
MqlDateTime time;
TimeToStruct(TimeCurrent(),time);
string currenttime=IntegerToString(time.year)+"-0"+
                      IntegerToString(time.mon)+"-"+
                      IntegerToString(time.day)+ " "+
                      IntegerToString(time.hour)+ ":"+
                      IntegerToString(time.min)+ ":00";
```

The output of the following was: `2018-7-25 15:8:00` where I was expecting the output as  `2018-07-25 15:08:00`, that is in 2 values the month and the min. But it is not converting the zero. The date time what I am giving is in the format `2018-07-25 15:08:00`, which is I am expecting to get after converting to string. But got something else.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think the minutes should have zero before it? according to the code you have, seems minutes are not without leading zero.

Anyway if you do not like `TimeToString`, try `StringFormat`.

```
string output=StringFormat("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00", 
               time.year,time.mon,time.day,time.hour,time.min);
```